# Streaming music to Windows Phone from PC in realtime

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-phone-8, naudio

I'm trying to develop a Windows application (WPF) which can stream whatever it is that is being played on the system over TCP connection (Local WiFi). On the receiving end I have Windows Phone 8 applications which can play the audio in realtime.

What I've tried:

1. Successfully established a connection and data transmission works.

   ```
    void sMixListner_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if (writer != null)
           {
               SocketHandler.SocketManager.sendDataToClients(e.Buffer);
           }
       }
       catch { }
   } 
    public void sendDataToClients(byte[] music)
   {
       foreach (Socket client in clients)
       {
           try
           {

               client.Send(music);

           }
           catch { }
       }

   }
   ```

The above code transmits whatever data is received from `WasapiLoopbackCapture` class.

1. On the Phone side I'm being able to properly receive all that byte[] data and I'm writing it into a MemoryStream.
    MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream();
    public void ReceiveMessage()
       {

   ```
       var responseListener = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
       responseListener.Completed += responseListener_Completed;

       var responseBuffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
       responseListener.SetBuffer(responseBuffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

       _socket.ReceiveAsync(responseListener);
   }

   void responseListener_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   {
       stream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred);
       if (!stopReceiving)
           ReceiveMessage();
   }
   ```

After receiving few seconds of it I'm trying to play it back as:

```
public void play()
{
SoundEffect soundE = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), 48000, AudioChannels.Mono);
soundE.CreateInstance();
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
isPlaying = true;
soundE.Play();
}
```

All I hear is noise. I've tried writing a WaveHeader to the stream in the following way (From Nokia developer site):

```
public void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int sampleRate)
    {
        const int bitsPerSample = 32;
        const int bytesPerSample = bitsPerSample / 8;
        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        // ChunkID Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form (0x52494646 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("RIFF"), 0, 4);

        // NOTE this will be filled in later
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(0), 0, 4);

        // Format Contains the letters "WAVE"(0x57415645 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("WAVE"), 0, 4);

        // Subchunk1ID Contains the letters "fmt " (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("fmt "), 0, 4);

        // Subchunk1Size 16 for PCM. This is the size of therest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(16), 0, 4);

        // AudioFormat PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization) Values other than 1 indicate some form of compression.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1), 0, 2);

        // NumChannels Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1), 0, 2);

        // SampleRate 8000, 44100, etc.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sampleRate), 0, 4);

        // ByteRate = SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sampleRate * bytesPerSample), 0, 4);

        // BlockAlign NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 The number of bytes for one sample including all channels.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(bytesPerSample)), 0, 2);

        // BitsPerSample 8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(bitsPerSample)), 0, 2);

        // Subchunk2ID Contains the letters "data" (0x64617461 big-endian form).
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("data"), 0, 4);

        // NOTE to be filled in later
        stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(0), 0, 4);
    }
```

The recording part is correct since if I write a .wav file using `WavFileWriter` the sound is just fine on playback.

Can someone help me out please? I need to be able to play that sound on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

WASAPI capture is 32 bit IEEE floating point, not 32 bit PCM, so your AudioFormat in the WAV header is wrong. IEEE is float, but in your case, I'd recommend converting to 16 bit before sending the audio across the network to save a bit on bandwidth.

Comment: Actually, I've never dealt with audio much before.. can you give me some links to help me out??

Comment: I go into this in a lot of detail in my [two Pluralsight courses on audio](http://pluralsight.com/training/Authors/Details/mark-heath) (apologies for shameless plug)